# Retornar Array hacia Python desde Java

Tags: java, python

Saludos tengo un archivo el cual me conecto hacia una db(MySQL) este archivo recibe como parametro un numero de 13 digitos(ruc) el mismo recibe bien, pero el problema surge al retornar la respuesta desde **JAVA** hacia **Python**
en python recibe como **Str** y no como **Array**.

Código de como invoco al jar desde Python:

```
import shlex, subprocess
import json

PARAMETRO = "1804464194001"
JAVA_CMD = 'java'
JAR_PATH = "catastro.jar"
command = [
    JAVA_CMD,
    '-jar',
    JAR_PATH,
    PARAMETRO
]
p = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    #shell=True
)

result = p.communicate()[0]
print(type(result))
```

El código de Java:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
....
try {
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        //data resultset
        String razonSocial = rs.getString("RAZON_SOCIAL");
        String nombreComercial = rs.getString("NOMBRE_COMERCIAL");
        String estadoContribuyente = rs.getString("ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE");
        String obligado = rs.getString("OBLIGADO");
        String tipoContribuyente = rs.getString("TIPO_CONTRIBUYENTE");
        String calle = rs.getString("CALLE");
        String numero = rs.getString("NUMERO");
        String interseccion = rs.getString("INTERSECCION");

        //data ArrayList
        result.add(razonSocial);
        result.add(nombreComercial);
        result.add(estadoContribuyente);
        result.add(obligado);
        result.add(tipoContribuyente);
        result.add(calle);
        result.add(numero);
        result.add(interseccion);

        //return result
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    conn.close();
    rs.close();
    st.close();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

lo que retorna desde java:

```
['DIEGO ALBERTO AVILA', '', 'ACTIVO', 'N', 'OTRO', 'CEVALLOS', 'S/N','MOLINA']
```

Entonces en teoria deberia ser un array y para esto intento acceder así:

```
print(result[0])
```

Mismo que me muestra:

```
[
```

Gracias por cualquier sugerencia..!!

Comment: Una forma 'sucia' pero rápida sería hacerlo un `eval('arr = ' + result)`

Comment: otra forma es `result[1:-1].split(",")` el 1:-1 es para quitar las llaves, el split es para cortar la cadena por comas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gracias a todos por sus comentarios tras leer varios blogs y comentarios halle la siguiente forma:

```
#respuesta de java
ini_list = p.communicate()[0]
#remover los corchetes y separa por cierto caracter(,) y lo convierte en list
res = ini_list.strip('][').split(',') 
# finalmente el resultado en list
print(type(res))
```

Resultado:

```
<type 'list'>
```

Claro existen otras mas como:

**Método 1**

```
import json
ini_list = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
print ("initial string", ini_list) 
print (type(ini_list)) 
res = json.loads(ini_list) 
print ("final list", res) 
print (type(res))
```

Resultado:

```
initial string [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
<class 'str'>
final list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
<class 'list'>
```

**Método 2:**

```
import ast 
ini_list = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
print ("initial string", ini_list) 
print (type(ini_list)) 
res = ast.literal_eval(ini_list) 
print ("final list", res) 
print (type(res))
```

Resultado:

```
initial string [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
<class 'str'>
final list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
<class 'list'>
```

Cabe mencionar que estos métodos no me funciono salvo el primero que coloque.

Espero sirva a alguien y gracias por sus sugerencias..!!

Answer (score 4):

## Retornar datos desde Java

Realmente, tu programa Java **no retorna** un Array (como indica el título de tu pregunta), sino que lo **imprime** por su salida estándar. Desde el momento que lo imprimes, obviamente pasa a ser una cadena.

Retornar *realmente* el array (mediante un `return`) implicaría que pudieras de algún modo desde Python cargar la clase Java, invocar su método y obtener el valor devuelto en forma de `list` python en lugar de Array java. Esto es en general muy complejo. Puede simplificarse mucho si en lugar del intérprete `python` usas otro llamado `jython` para ejecutar tu programa, pues este intérprete está escrito en Java y puede interactuar con otras clases java de forma nativa.

No obstante, usar Jython me parece excesivo para un caso tan simple como este, pero podría ser una buena solución si el método Java retornara algo más complejo, como una instancia de una clase con sus datos y sus métodos, que contuviera quizás referencias a otros objetos, etc.

## Serialización

El problema de convertir una estructura de datos más o menos compleja en una secuencia de bytes se denomina en general *serialización*. Un caso particular es cuando quieres convertirlo a texto, pues al final una cadena no es más que una secuencia de bytes.

Al imprimir el Array desde Java has resuelto de una forma muy simple el problema de la serialización, pues Java contiene métodos para mostrar la lista de forma serializada sin tener tú que iterar por los elementos. Este método funcionará también si dentro de la lista sus elementos fuesen otras listas, pues las serializaría de forma recursiva.

Para leer ese texto desde python *y volver a convertirlo en la estructura de datos original* (una lista) tienes el problema inverso, llamado *deserialización*.

La solución que propones basada en ignorar los corchetes que rodean la representación textual de la lista, y después partir sus elementos por las comas, te funciona en este caso, pero es en general muy frágil. ¿Y si los elementos de la lista fuesen cadenas, y alguna de estas cadenas contuviese comas? ¿Y si los elementos de la lista fuesen otras listas? ¿Y si fuesen otro tipo de datos como por ejemplo un `Map<k,v>`?

Creo que la solución más general, a la vez que sencilla, es utilizar **JSON** como representación intermedia. Es decir:

- Desde java, conviertes tu dato a JSON, lo que lo convierte en una cadena de texto, e imprimes la cadena resultante. Puedes usar la biblioteca [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) para esto, usando por ejemplo `System.println(gson.toJson(result);`
- Desde python, recibes el texto y lo transformas desde JSON a una estructura python nativa usando `json.loads()`

En este caso tan sencillo puedes ahorrarte el `Gson` en la parte Java, pues dará el mismo resultado que el `System.println()` directo que tú has intentado, pero en casos más complicados (elementos que sean cadenas, o sublistas, o diccionarios) esta solución será mucho más genérica.

Comment: Saludos, he probado tu solucion y obtengo el error "No JSON object could be decoded" ya cambiando la metodologia con gson y json.loads

Comment: Hola @DiegoAvila. Ese error quién te lo da, java o python? Entiendo que python, pues es quien tiene que hacer la operación "decode". ¿Cómo lo has intentado? Debería ser tan simple como `lista = json.loads(result)`, pero asegúrate antes de lo que tienes en `result`, imprimiéndolo en pantalla por si acaso.

Comment: efectivamente me devuelve el ArrayList tipo string por lo cual no devuelve como json desde java

Comment: Un JSON es al final un string, no sé si te estoy entendiendo bien el problema.  Debería ser tan simple como instanciar un objeto `gson` de la clase `Gson` y luego hacer `gson.toJson(tu_lista)` para obtener la versión cadena que imprimirías, en la parte Java. El resultado sería una cadena como `"[1,2,3]"`, por ejemplo. Pero es que este formato de ponerlo entre corchetes y separado por comas, es el que usa JSON para representar listas.

Answer (score 2):

Encontré en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250396/converting-string-that-looks-like-a-list-into-a-real-list-python) que existe un módulo justo para convertir un str con forma de objeto en el objeto Python adecuado, y es más seguro que un simple `eval`, porque lanza una excepción cuando el resultado no es un tipo de dato de Python válido:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(result)
```