# Convertir a lista una string previamente hecha de una lista de listas

Tags: python, lista

soy muy nuevo en python y tengo un socket. Necesito mandarle al cliente una matriz así que lo convertí primero a string con

```
cadena=""
cadena+='/'.join(str(x) for x in lista)
```

De lado del cliente necesito regresar esa string a lista pero si lo hago con `matriz1=matrizCad.replace('[','').replace(']','').split('/')` pero regresa algo asi:

```
'elemento', 'elemento', ...
'elemento', 'elemento', ...
.
.
.
'elemento', 'elemento'
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerle para que quite las apostrofes y las comas para que solo queden los elementos?

Comment: Para esto sirve la librería json, con json.dumps llevas cualquier estructura a un string y con json.loads lo conviertes nuevamente a un objeto de python. No es necesario re-inventar la rueda.

Comment: Hay una pregunta diferente pero con el mismo problema, te linkeo las soluciones posibles: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/281911/131763

Answer (score 2):

Si el cliente y servidor están programados en Python, y los objetos que estas enviando son tipos nativos de Python (integer, strings, lista y/o diccionarios), puedes utilizar las bondades de serialización y de-serializacipon de la librería `json`, incluida en Python.

A modo de ejemplo, lo siguiente se aplica al caso de uso que describes en la pregunta:

```
import json

# tenemos una lista arbitraria en python
lista = [1, 2, 'foo', {'name': 'john'}, [9, 10]]

# la transformamos a string
lista_serializada = json.dumps(lista)

# imprimimos los valores para checkear que este OK
print(type(lista_serializada))
# <class 'str'>

print(lista_serializada)
# '[1, 2, "foo", {"name": "john"}, [9, 10]]'
# notar que esto es un string    

# transformamos este string a una lista nuevamente
nueva_lista = json.loads(lista_serializada)

# para checkear que es consistente
print(lista == nueva_lista)
# True
```

Esto funciona en la composicion de estos tipos también, asi que cuando mencionas una matriz, me imagino que te refieres a una lista de listas (dado que el tipo matriz no existe en Python), por lo que funcionaría para tu caso.